# Tracking the amount of time a number is greater than 0 in SQL

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, inventory

I'm trying to figure out a way to keep track of how long a part has a QTY greater than 0. I've setup a table in SQL Server like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Levels] (
    RecordID    INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Timestamp   DATETIME DEFAULT(current_timestamp) NOT NULL,
    Part        VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    QTY         INT NOT NULL
)
```

With this I only need to use the Part and QTY column when I'm doing an insert statement. I want all of the parts that I'm keeping track of to start off at 0, then to have some QTY then to go back to 0. I've used the following queries to populate the table for now, with a small delay inbetween each pair.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Levels] (Part, QTY) VALUES('PART1234', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Levels] (Part, QTY) VALUES('ITEM5678', 0)
```

and a few seconds later.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Levels] (Part, QTY) VALUES('PART1234', 5)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Levels] (Part, QTY) VALUES('ITEM5678', 19)
```

and then a few more seconds.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Levels] (Part, QTY) VALUES('PART1234', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Levels] (Part, QTY) VALUES('ITEM5678', 0)
```

I now have this data in my table.

```
  RecordID    Timestamp               Part       QTY
----------- ----------------------- ---------- -----------
1           2017-05-23 13:56:57.123 PART1234   0
2           2017-05-23 13:56:57.123 ITEM5678   0
3           2017-05-23 13:57:00.857 PART1234   5
4           2017-05-23 13:57:00.890 ITEM5678   19
5           2017-05-23 13:57:02.827 PART1234   0
6           2017-05-23 13:57:02.827 ITEM5678   0
```

Now that I have all of the data I need I need to figure out how to see how long an item has had a QTY greater than 0.

For example, I could calculate that PART1234 was in stock for 1.97 seconds, but how can I get this from a single SQL Query in the following format so I can see all of the parts and a total time in stock even if they are going in and out of stock in this table?

```
Part     InStockPeriod
-------- ----------------
PART1234 00:00:01.9700000
ITEM5678 00:00:01.9366667
```

Thank you,

With a little tweaking of Kannan Kandasamy's answer I arrived at this. While it does not return in a time format, it does return the seconds that an item was in stock properly and will update based on the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if the item is currently in stock.

```
WITH Thing as (
SELECT *,
        [TimeDiff] = CONVERT(TIME, 
            CASE
                WHEN LEAD(TIMESTAMP, 1, [TimeStamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY Part ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) <> [Timestamp] THEN
                    lead(TIMESTAMP, 1, [TimeStamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY Part ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) - [Timestamp]
                ELSE
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - [TimeStamp]
            END)
    FROM [Levels])
SELECT   Part, 
         sum( DATEPART(SECOND, [TimeDiff]) + 60 * 
              DATEPART(MINUTE, [TimeDiff]) + 3600 * 
              DATEPART(HOUR, [TimeDiff] ) 
            ) as 'TotalTime' 
FROM Thing WHERE QTY > 0
GROUP BY Part
```

With the sample data it returns this.

```
Part       TotalTime
---------- -----------
ITEM5678   1
PART1234   1
```

And if I add a record saying ITEM5678 is in stock again.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Levels] (Part, QTY) VALUES('ITEM5678',1)
```

Then the query will start counting up in seconds as long as the most recent record for that item is greater than 0.

```
Part       TotalTime
---------- -----------
ITEM5678   20
PART1234   1
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you have a flag letting you know if the adjustment to inventory is going up or down? It seems that you're simply updating a fact and a "change" in number can be hiding items going in AND out of stock - meaning you're only showing the net change. Is this intentional?

Comment: I do not currently, but that would be very easy to add. My plan was to log inventory changes, as in; I would pull our inventory numbers on a regular basis and anytime the QTY for a particular item was different from the last time I checked it then I would insert it into this table. That way I can see the QTYs as they change over time but also hopefully to see how much time a product is in stock and out of stock with this. So the QTY column is not a net change but the actual QTY at that moment in time. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lead and get time difference as below:

```
select [Part], --sum(TimeDiff) as InStockPeriod 
    sum(datepart(ms,timediff)/60.00) InStockSeconds
 from (
    select *,
        [TimeDiff] = convert(time, lead(timestamp, 1, [TimeStamp]) over (partition by Part order by [TimeStamp])- [Timestamp])
        --, lead(timestamp) over (partition by Part order by [TimeStamp]) 
    from levels
) a
group by [part]
```

But it will get data into seconds we need to convert it into time format

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the query but when I try this with the data I provided above it returns this.

Part: ITEM5678 InStockSeconds: 28.366666

And ITEM5678 would not have been in stock for 28 seconds. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Logic here is to get next timestamp to the current row using lead function and find the difference and do the sum... You can try executing inner query alone uncommenting lead you will get better understanding

Comment: I was able to get your query to work after tweaking it a bit. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Welcome, Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I think a recursive CTE will work. Tested with SQL Server 2008R2:

```
WITH levelsRanked AS 
(
    SELECT
                l.*
                ,levelRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.Part ORDER BY l.RecordID DESC)
    FROM
                [dbo].[Levels]      l
),levelsCTE AS
(
    SELECT
                lr.RecordID
                ,lr.[Timestamp]
                ,lr.Part
                ,lr.QTY
                ,lr.levelRank
                ,TimeSinceChange    = 0
    FROM
                levelsRanked    lr
    WHERE
                lr.levelRank        = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      
                lr.RecordID
                ,lr.[Timestamp]
                ,lr.Part
                ,lr.QTY
                ,lr.levelRank
                ,TimeSinceChange    = DATEDIFF(SECOND, lr.[Timestamp], lc.[Timestamp])
    FROM
                levelsRanked    lr
    INNER JOIN
                levelsCTE       lc
        ON
                lr.Part             = lc.part
            AND lr.levelRank        = lc.levelRank + 1
    WHERE
                lr.levelRank        > 1
)
SELECT
        *
FROM
        levelsCTE
WHERE
        qty > 0
```

You can then do a `GROUP BY` to get the total amount of time an item has been in-stock if it's going to move in and out of stock multiple times.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this query, when I run it I'm getting negative numbers for the time since change column, would I be calculating the total in stock time using the timestamp column in combination with the seconds in the time since change column?

Comment: Sorry, I had to reverse the ORDER BY and should have updated the CTE. Fixed that to return positive numbers. To get the totals, do something like this at the end of the CTE: `SELECT
        Part
  ,TotalTimeInStock = SUM(TimeSinceChange)
FROM
        levelsCTE
WHERE
        qty > 0
GROUP BY
  Part`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
with one as
(select a.* from
(
select Part,qty,Timestamp,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Part order by 
Timestamp desc) as RowNum from [Levels]
)a
where RowNum<=2)
select a.Part,DATEDIFF(SS,b.Timestamp,a.Timestamp) as InStockPeriod from one 
a inner join one b on a.RowNum+1=b.RowNum and a.Part=b.Part
where a.RowNum=1 and a.QTY=0
```

Comment: This works, but it only returns parts where the most recent record is 0, if the most recent record is greater than 0 it won't show them. But I think you're on the right track, I'm working with both of the queries that have been posted as answers at the moment.